# How to fix my implementation of js bind?

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I'm prepping for interviews and wanted to write my own implementation of the JS bind function. I am referencing this polyfill code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

The test comes back

```
 Expected value to equal:
      42
 Received:
      undefined
```

**Thank you for your help in identifying the issue with the bind2 function, and if you could describe how you would debug a function that references this?**

gist: https://gist.github.com/Falieson/580e4feb26e92ece7d93b102c78a6f76

the bind2.ts function

```
// tslint:disable no-any

export default function bind2(this: any, that: any) {
  const f = this // tslint:disable-line no-this-assignment
  const initialArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)

  return (finalArgs: any[]) => f.apply(that, [...initialArgs, ...finalArgs])
}
```

the bind2.test.ts

```
// tslint:disable no-any
import bind2 from '../bind2'

function decorate(obj: any): any {
  const res = new Function()
  Object.assign(res, obj)
  res['bind2'] = bind2 // tslint:disable-line no-string-literal
  return res
}

describe('.bind2(target)', () => {
  test('works', () => {
    const data = {
      getX() {
        return this.x
      },
      x: 42,
    }
    const unboundGetX = data.getX
    const boundGetX = decorate(unboundGetX).bind2(data)

    expect(boundGetX()).toEqual(42)
  })
})
```

Comment: So what is the problem you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `that` as `this` of `boundGetX()`, but `that` param is `undefined`.

```
export default function bind2(data: any) {
  const initialArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)

  return (finalArgs: any[]) => this.apply(data, [...initialArgs, ...finalArgs])
};

function decorate(obj: any): any {
  obj.bind2 = bind2
  return obj
}
```

Comment: console.log src/helpers/globals/bind2.ts:6
    { this: { [Function: anonymous] bind2: [Function: bind2] },
      that: { getX: [Function: getX], x: 42 },
      initialArgs: [] }
. `that` is defined and is the new `this` the function is applied to

Comment: @Falieson Don't need to be so complicated, I can't understand your needs.

Comment: thanks, I was using decorator model from another test. I think for some reason this part of `decorate()` was breaking it:  `const res = new Function()
  Object.assign(res, obj)`